# Filter a specific letter within a word using Grep

Tags: grep

I've been trying to find a way to filter a specific letter within a word using a regular expression. For exemple, filtering the letter "a" in the word "latin". Filtering only a letter would be simple using something like :

```
grep "\ba\b"
```

but I can't find a way to get the "a" only in a certain word.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"? To remove the letter? As in "latin" -> "ltin"?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe to another grep, like this:

```
grep "\ba\b" /path/to/input/file | grep -o "a"
```

The latter part of the pipe uses the `o` flag which only outputs the matched part. Alternatively `grep -o "a"` should return all a's.